# Kotlin io socket never reaches backend

Tags: php, android, sockets, kotlin, websocket

I have a PHP backend, that creates a websocket server with Ratchet and a Kotlin frontend.
When I try to connect to my backend server with another computer, it works perfectly fine. (So I made sure, it´s not a firewall problem) On the other computer I just copied the example from the tutorial and entered:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://<my-ip>:80');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

and I log new connections on the server. Which indeed reacted to that call with a log of a new connection. However, interesting enough, the browser on the other pc never logged "Connection established!".
But when I try to connect with my Android phone using my Kotlin app, it is even worse: The connection never even reaches the backend! There´s no log saying a new connection established. In addition the Socket on the phone never fires the "Connection" event.
Here`s how I initialize the Socket in Kotlin. I am using 'io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.1':

```
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import java.net.URI
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var socket : Socket
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
        val uri = URI.create("ws://192.168.1.23:80")
        val options = IO.Options.builder().build()
        socket = IO.socket(uri, options)
    }
    fun onSend(view : View) {
        val message = Message(//some values)
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z").create()
        val jsonObject = gson.toJson(message)
        socket.once("message") {
           @Override
           fun call(vararg args : Objects) {
               val response = args[0]
           }
        }
        socket.connect()
               .once(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
                     socket.send(jsonObject)
                }
                .once(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {
                     socket.send(jsonObject)
                }
    }
```

Yes, I am totally aware, that there is absolutely no sense to sending on connection error, but I just needed some random line I could break on, to see if it even reaches there.
This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.appthem">
        <activity android:name=".activities.ChatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

On backend I work with Ratchet.
Have a simple Connection-File, that doesn´t do much more than establishing connection right now:

```
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;

class SocketConnection implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected \SplObjectStorage $clients;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        error_log("New client attached");
    }

    function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }

    function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        //do some message stuff then
    }
}
```

Dependency is `"cboden/ratchet": "0.4.3.*"`
And then I have my server.php like that:

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use agroSMS\Websockets\SocketConnection;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new SocketConnection()
        )
    )
);

$server->run();
```

Which I start from the command shell. Like I said, when the other laptop connects with a JS websocket, it logs the connection, when I try to connect with my Android phone, no log, nothing seems to reach the backend. Did I forget something?

Edit:
To ensure clarity, the "onSend"-method is called on a button press. Didn´t include the xml-file here (since I didn´t consider it relevant), but I know, that it is being called, since the debugger stops at the breakpoint first line in the onSend-method.

Edit 2:
I finally managed to get a connection_error and logged it into my console. The error message returned is the following:

```
[{"cause":{"detailMessage":"426","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"xhr poll error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
```

But I really don´t understand where this poll error could come from. It was on an emulator, so there is no wifi-issue.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: But wouldn´t the app crash on any exception? There´s no crash. It just keeps running.

Comment: This may sound like a silly question and maybe I'm missing something here but are you actually calling the `onSend` function in your `ChatActivity`? That's the bit that should establish the connection to your backend.

Comment: @Selim Yes, it´s an onclick listener on a button. :D Didn´t include the button in there. But I also sat breakpoints at first line of onSend-function and it reaches there and goes through the whole function. Just never coming inside of the event listeners.

Comment: Can you try setting `usesCleartextTraffic` to true in your manifest? You can find the docs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.

Comment: Already did that, since I already had problems with the Retrofit because of that, which I was able to solve that way.

Answer (score 1):

As you might guess, as soon as you know the error, you´re not far from the solution:
So, all that was missing, was a single line, setting the transport method to Websocket.
Correct initialization in Kotlin:

```
try {
       val uri = URI.create("ws://<my-ip>:80")
       val options = IO.Options.builder()
                    .setTimeout(60000)
                    .setTransports(arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME))
                    .build()
       socket = IO.socket(uri, options)
    }catch(e : Exception) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        }
```

However, even though this solved the issue of the Kotlin request not reaching the server, it didn´t solve the problem, that the established connection is not reported back to the frontend. The connection_event still doesn´t get triggered.